# Symfony warning translation not found

Tags: symfony, translation

I have an error:

> warning translation not found.

So I have try this command:

```
app/console translation:update
```

But I have that error :

> [RuntimeException]
>       Not enough arguments (missing: "locale").

In my `config.yml` I add

```
parameters:
    locale: fr
```

But always the same error.

Answer (score 4):

You're missing an extra parameter. For example, to update English translation:

```
 app/console translation:update en --force
```

`"en"` parameter is the locale you want to update, and `--force` could be changed by `--dump-messages` if you just want to view the translateable strings.

Comment: Thanks, i have try this command, but i have again : [WARNING] No translation found.

Comment: Are you sure you have the translation file in the correct directory? And when is this message appearing?

Comment: This message appeared when  i execute a specific command, i  can't post the command, its specific to my job :/.
Where i can found this directory ? I have a folder 'translations' in app/resources, its that ?

Comment: and i have too this message when i use : php app/console translation:update fr --force

Comment: You can follow the instructions given in http://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html